# PHP Password Protecting

Tags: php, header, md5, setcookie

I'm having difficulty trying to password-protect a section of my website. I'm not too familiar with php, so I'm using code from zubrag.com as a starting point. The problem I'm running into is that I get an error with the current code that states:

`cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/index.php:78) in /var/www/index.php on line 333`

I've looked at like 78, I get it, my outputs start there because that's the first line that the php bracket is at.

At line 333 is my `setcookie` command. I also understand that in order to have a cookie set, it needs to be done in the header. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how I can do that with my code. I've looked online and found that generally the best way to fix this is through the use of `ob_start()` and `ob_end_flush()`. Well, I tried placing those commands at numerous places and have had no luck as of yet.

I've set `ob_start` at the beginning of the file, before everything else. I've also tried at the beginning of the case and have had no luck.

I've set `ob_end_flush` at the end of the file and at the end of the case, and I've had no luck with that either.

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>DVR Controls</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/superfish.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/superfish-navbar.css" /> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/hoverIntent.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/superfish.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        // initialise plugins
        jQuery(function(){
            jQuery('ul.sf-menu').superfish();
        });

        </script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){ 
                $("ul.sf-menu").superfish({ 
                    pathClass:  'current' 
                }); 
        });

        </script>

        <center><b><font size="36">The Radeus DVR Prototype</font></b></center>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul class="sf-menu sf-navbar">
            <li class="current">
                <a>Configuration</a>
                <ul>

                    <li>
                        <a href="index.php?page=SysConfig">System Configuration</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="index.php?page=FileConfig">File Configuration</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="index.php?page=NetworkConfig">Network Configuration</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="index.php?page=Files">Files</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="index.php?page=Maintenance">Maintenance Mode</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="index.php?page=IETM">IETM</a>
            </li>   
            <li>
                <a>Power Options</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.php?page=Shutdown">Shutdown</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="index.php?page=Reboot">Reboot</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>


    </body>
<br><br><br><br><br>
<body>
<br>
<?php
ob_start();
$currentdir = '/data/'; //Location of Hard Drive

/**
 * @func: Executes the command passed to it as argument and prints the
 * command console output line by line onto the html output stream hence
* giving the illusion of having the command executing in the html window itself.
 */

function html_exec_cmd($cmd)    {
    $proc = popen("($cmd)2>&1", "r");
    echo '<pre>';
    while(!feof($proc)) {
        $result = fgets($proc, 100);
        echo htmlspecialchars($result);
        flush();
    }
    pclose($proc);
    echo '</pre>';
}

switch ($_GET['page'])
{

    case 'SysConfig':
          echo "Welcome to System Config!";
    break;

    case 'FileConfig':
          echo "Welcome to File Config!";
    break;

    case 'NetworkConfig':

?>
<b><fontsize="16">Current Settings:</b></font>



<?php

html_exec_cmd('ifconfig eth0'); 



     break;

     case 'Files':





    $FileCount = 0;
    $dir = opendir($currentdir);
    $array = array();
    echo '<ul>';



echo '<form method = "post" action = "">';

while ($File = readdir($dir)){

echo '<form action="test.php" method = "post">';

//if (is_file($file))

    $ext = pathinfo($File, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if ($ext == '264'){


    $array[] = "$File";

    echo "<INPUT class='radio' type='radio' name='FileName' value='$File' /> <span>$File</span><p>";    

    $FileCount++;   
    }

    }




    echo "<INPUT TYPE = 'Submit' name = 'FormSubmit' value = 'Submit'>";

    echo '</form>';


    if ($_POST['FormSubmit'] == "Submit")
    {
    $FileParameters = $_POST['FileName'];

    $FileExecuteCommand = "cd //; /etc/init.d/matrix-gui-e stop;echo 0 > /sys/devices/platform/vpss/graphics0/enabled;./usr/share/ti/ti-omx/    decode_display_a8host_debug.xv5T -w 1920 -h 1080 -f 60 -c h264 -g 0 -d 0 -i $currentdir$FileParameters;/etc/init.d/matrix-gui-e start";


    echo exec($FileExecuteCommand);



     }




     break;


     case 'Maintenance':


###############################################################
# Page Password Protect 2.13
###############################################################
# Visit http://www.zubrag.com/scripts/ for updates
############################################################### 
#
# Usage:
# Set usernames / passwords below between SETTINGS START and SETTINGS END.
# Open it in browser with "help" parameter to get the code
# to add to all files being protected. 
#    Example: password_protect.php?help
# Include protection string which it gave you into every file that needs to be protected
#
# Add following HTML code to your page where you want to have logout link
# <a href="http://www.example.com/path/to/protected/page.php?logout=1">Logout</a>
#
###############################################################

/*
-------------------------------------------------------------------
SAMPLE if you only want to request login and password on login form.
Each row represents different user.

$LOGIN_INFORMATION = array(
  'zubrag' => 'root',
  'test' => 'testpass',
  'admin' => 'passwd'
);

--------------------------------------------------------------------
SAMPLE if you only want to request only password on login form.
Note: only passwords are listed

$LOGIN_INFORMATION = array(
  'root',
  'testpass',
  'passwd'
);

--------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

##################################################################
#  SETTINGS START
##################################################################

// Add login/password pairs below, like described above
// NOTE: all rows except last must have comma "," at the end of line
$LOGIN_INFORMATION = array(
  'admin' => 'adminpass'
);

// request login? true - show login and password boxes, false - password box only
define('USE_USERNAME', true);

// User will be redirected to this page after logout
define('LOGOUT_URL', 'http://www.example.com/');

// time out after NN minutes of inactivity. Set to 0 to not timeout
define('TIMEOUT_MINUTES', 3);

// This parameter is only useful when TIMEOUT_MINUTES is not zero
// true - timeout time from last activity, false - timeout time from login
define('TIMEOUT_CHECK_ACTIVITY', true);

##################################################################
#  SETTINGS END
##################################################################


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// do not change code below
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// show usage example
if(isset($_GET['help'])) {
  die('Include following code into every page you would like to protect, at the very beginning (first line):<br>&lt;?php include("' . str_replace('\\','\\\\',__FILE__) . '"); ?&gt;');
}

// timeout in seconds
$timeout = (TIMEOUT_MINUTES == 0 ? 0 : time() + TIMEOUT_MINUTES * 60);

// logout?
if(isset($_GET['logout'])) {
  setcookie("verify", '', $timeout, '/'); // clear password;
  header('Location: ' . LOGOUT_URL);
  exit();
}

if(!function_exists('showLoginPasswordProtect')) {

// show login form
function showLoginPasswordProtect($error_msg) {
?>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Please enter password to access this page</title>
  <META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
  <META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
</head>
<body>
  <style>
    input { border: 1px solid black; }
  </style>
  <div style="width:500px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; text-align:center">
  <form method="post">
    <h3>Please enter password to access this page</h3>
    <font color="red"><?php echo $error_msg; ?></font><br />
<?php if (USE_USERNAME) echo 'Login:<br /><input type="input" name="access_login" /><br />Password:<br />'; ?>
    <input type="password" name="access_password" /><p></p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
  <br />
  </div>
</body>
</html>

<?php
  // stop at this point
  die();
}
}

// user provided password

if (isset($_POST['access_password'])) {

  $login = isset($_POST['access_login']) ? $_POST['access_login'] : '';
  $pass = $_POST['access_password'];
  if (!USE_USERNAME && !in_array($pass, $LOGIN_INFORMATION)
  || (USE_USERNAME && ( !array_key_exists($login, $LOGIN_INFORMATION) || $LOGIN_INFORMATION[$login] != $pass ) ) 
  ) {
    showLoginPasswordProtect("Incorrect password.");
  }
  else {
    // set cookie if password was validated
    setcookie("verify", md5($login.'%'.$pass), $timeout, '/');

    // Some programs (like Form1 Bilder) check $_POST array to see if parameters passed
    // So need to clear password protector variables
    unset($_POST['access_login']);
    unset($_POST['access_password']);
    unset($_POST['Submit']);
  }

}

else {

  // check if password cookie is set
  if (!isset($_COOKIE['verify'])) {
    showLoginPasswordProtect("");
  }

  // check if cookie is good
  $found = false;
  foreach($LOGIN_INFORMATION as $key=>$val) {
    $lp = (USE_USERNAME ? $key : '') .'%'.$val;
    if ($_COOKIE['verify'] == md5($lp)) {
      $found = true;
      // prolong timeout
      if (TIMEOUT_CHECK_ACTIVITY) {
        setcookie("verify", md5($lp), $timeout, '/');
      }
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!$found) {
    showLoginPasswordProtect("");
  }

}





?>

<B><fontsize=16>Are you sure you want to Format the data disk?</b></font><br><br>

<?php
echo '<form method = "post">';

echo "<INPUT TYPE = 'Submit' name = 'FormatSubmit' value = 'Submit'>";

?>
<br><br><br>
Please check the box to verify you want to Format the data disk.

<Input type = 'Checkbox' Name ='FormatCheck' value ="checked">

<?php
echo '</form>';
if (($_POST['FormatSubmit'] == "Submit") & ($_POST['FormatCheck'] == "checked"))
    {
    html_exec_cmd('echo -e "o\nn\np\n1\n\n\nw\n" | fdisk /dev/sda;sleep 1;mkfs.ext3 /dev/sda1;mount /dev/sda1 /data/');
     }

ob_end_flush();
     break;


     case 'IETM':
          echo "Welcome to IETM";
     break;

        case 'Shutdown':
          //echo "Welcome to Shutdown";

?>

<B><fontsize=16>Are you sure you want to shutdown the DVR?</b></font><br><br>

<?php
echo '<form method = "post">';

echo "<INPUT TYPE = 'Submit' name = 'ShutDownSubmit' value = 'Submit'>";

?>
<br><br><br>
Please check the box to verify you want to shutdown the DVR.

<Input type = 'Checkbox' Name ='ShutDownCheck' value ="checked">

<?php
echo '</form>';
if (($_POST['ShutDownSubmit'] == "Submit") & ($_POST['ShutDownCheck'] == "checked"))
    {
    $ShutDownCommand = "init 0";
    echo exec($ShutDownCommand);

     }

     break;

     case 'Reboot':
          //echo "Welcome to Reboot";

?>

<B><fontsize=16>Are you sure you want to reboot the DVR?</b></font><br>
<br>
<?php

echo '<form method = "post">';
echo "<INPUT TYPE = 'Submit' name = 'RebootSubmit' value = 'Submit'>";
?>
<br><br><br>
Please check the box to verify you want to reboot the DVR.

<Input type = 'Checkbox' Name ='RebootCheck' value ="checked">

<?php

if (($_POST['RebootSubmit'] == "Submit")& ($_POST['RebootCheck'] == "checked"))
{
    $RebootCommand = "reboot";
    echo exec($RebootCommand);

     }

echo '</form>';
     break;  

    default :
           echo "The Radeus DVR";

}  
?>
</body>

</html>
<?php ob_end_flush(); ?>
```

Comment: If you're going to use a piece of technology with which you are unfamiliar in order to guarantee* security on your site, **don't**.  Make sure you understand all the risks and techniques on security before implementing any kind of solution. **guarantee is used loosely*

Comment: It's an internal website, security is not really necessary. It's more of a check. All people have access to the password.

Answer (score 3):

If you are going to use PHP's `header` function it must be called before any response is sent to the user. In this case the response preventing this from working is the HTML at the top of your page that comes before your PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a bit of javascript in a PHP echo statement to do the redirect and avoid the PHP header issue altogether. For instance:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript"> window.location = "login.php"; </script>';
```